# Spring authentication won't work

Tags: spring-security

So I'm trying to create spring authentication using hibernate. I've checked out probably all of the tutorials about this issue that are available on the internet and yet I seem to be missing something, because when I press the submit button in my form, no authentication is performed and I don't get redirected where I was supposed to be redirected...

This is my security configuration:

```
<bean id='userDetailsService' class='fi.social.web.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl'></bean>

 <security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
 </security:http>

 <bean id='daoAuthenticationProvider' class='org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider'>
    <property name='userDetailsService' ref='userDetailsService' />
 </bean>

 <bean id='authenticationManager' class='org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager'>
    <property name='providers'>
        <list>
            <ref local='daoAuthenticationProvider' />
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService'>
        <security:password-encoder hash='plaintext' />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

and my JSP page:

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />">
    <table style="position:absolute; right:15px;">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="<fmt:message key="user.usernameOrEmail"/>"/></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="<fmt:message key="user.password"/>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="color: white; text-align:right">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" /><fmt:message key="user.remember" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 15px; display:inline;" value="<fmt:message key="user.logIn"/>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Still, for some reason, when I submit the form I go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/social/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=C00D6F0CA27E3B359A9B04B8FADDD87F
```

even though the spring is supposed to know that my form is there and that it should process the parameters...
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the code, it looks like you're implementing Spring Social which is an implementation that will authenticate against facebook / twitter / ... if I remember correctly. Is this what you're trying to implement? 
http://www.springsource.org/spring-social
You mentioned Hibernate, I'm assuming you want to be implementing local authentication then?

Comment: oh! no, the name "social" is just a coincidence. I didn't realise there was some spring social for integration with other services :P I want to create a simple authentication based on my own database.

Comment: What happens when you put this on your page?
<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />
What does it output?

Comment: it's just like in URL "j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=98CCBDF8D83C4C215D36FAB6038AFF40 "

Comment: as far as I know, the url is correct, but the authentication process for some reason does not get triggered, although based on the spring configuration, it should be

Comment: Is that your complete security config? Update post with a copy paste of your config, just hash out anything that shouldn't public.

Comment: but this is actually all...

Comment: I don't see an http tag or anything that's being secured. Have a look at the official doc's example: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal

Comment: I know... but for some reason when I try to write just <http> eclipse gives me the following error:
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans"]}' is expected.

Comment: And tomee gives me this one, when I try to deploy it after all:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set up your login form just using `<form method="post" name="loginForm" action='#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check'>`

Also there is one odd thing on your configuration (but from what you are telling that is not the problem right now):

It's that you are declaring two `authentication managers`:

`<security:authentication-manager>,

<bean id='authenticationManager' class='org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager'>`

Try removing

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService'>
        <security:password-encoder hash='plaintext' />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```